# trouble with passing class method data to outside function

Tags: functions, shortcode, array, csv

I'm attempting to call a function using this shortcode format:

```
[priceguide file='test.csv' type='mods']
```

When I do this, all I get back on the page is the file name, `test.csv`, and nothing else.

The function I'm trying to call is supposed to receive a file name, `test.csv`, open that file and parse values from it, then pass it to an array which becomes `$data`.

Then according to `type`, the function calls another function which should display some HTML, that is dependent on values coming from `open_csv`.

The csv file is present in the plugin folder, is named correctly in both the shortcode and it's actual file name, and is not corrupted.

---

```
add_shortcode( 'priceguide', [ new MyPlugin, 'open_csv' ] );
    class MyPlugin
        {
            private $data = [];
        public function __construct()
        {
            add_filter( 'get_my_plugin_instance', [ $this, 'get_instance' ] );
        }
        public function get_instance()
        {
            return $this;
        }
        public function open_csv( $atts ) {
        $attributes = shortcode_atts( array(
            'file' => '',
            'type' => '',
        ), $atts );
        $handle = fopen( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . $attributes['file'] , "r" );  
        $this->data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    if (in_array("mods", $attributes)) {
        displaymodshtml();
    }
    elseif (in_array("items", $attributes)) {
        displayitemshtml();
    }
    return $attributes['file', 'type'];
    }
}
        function displaymodshtml () {
        ob_start();
        echo('<input type="text" class="search" id="search" placeholder="Search">');
        echo('<br>');
        echo('<table id="table">    <tr class="hidden">
            <th><b>
                Name</b>
            </th>
            <th><b>
                Cheese</b>
            </th>
            <th><b>
                Price (Pesos)</b>
            </th>
            <th><b>Vote</b>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>');
        $CSVData = new MyPlugin;
        $ModsData = $CSVData->data;
        // assign variables to array values
        while ($ModsData !== FALSE) {
            $name = $ModsData[0];
            $quanid = $ModsData[2];
            $table = $ModsData[3];
            unset($ModsData[2]);
            unset($ModsData[3]);
        //generate HTML
        echo('<tr>');
        foreach ($ModsData as $index=>$val) {
            echo('<td>');
            echo htmlentities($val, ENT_QUOTES);
            echo('</td>');  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked in detail at your code, but what strikes me is your `open_csv` method.

You have the following lines

- `return $attributes['file'];`
- `return $attributes['type'];`

As your method currently stands, it stops and returns the value of `file` right after setting the attributes. Here is what [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) does in php

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.

Your solution would be to remove those two lines or modify your method to return the values later in an appropriate place like at the end of your method

Comment: Code edited, altered return statement.